# Reverse output of right triangle-Java

Tags: java

I have been given a program that will print a right triangle from right to left of six rows, almost like stairs, with a space between each #. I have written an answer however and the output goes from left to right. How can I change the print?

This is what I have written:

```
/**
 * Created by User on 08/10/2015.
 */
class Stars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int row, numberOfHashes;

        for (row = 1; row <= 6; row++) {
            for(numberOfHashes = 1; numberOfHashes <= row; numberOfHashes++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + "#");
            }
            System.out.println(); // Go to next line
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output

```
    #
    #   #
    #   #   #
    #   #   #   #
    #   #   #   #   #
    #   #   #   #   #   #
```

How can I have it printed so the output will peint from right to left, with 1 on the top and row 6 on the bottom?

Comment: I have shown effort, I wrote the original program! When I reversed the 2nd loop it said there was too much output and the IDE froze. How do I edit the code above to get what I want?

Comment: If you are going to try and be clever, please write it in English. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to your loop- before printing the hashes, print the blanks you need

```
class Stars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int row, numberOfHashes;

        for (row = 1; row <= 6; row++) {
            for(numberOfBlanks = 1; numberOfBlanks <= 6 - row; numberOfBlanks++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + " ");
            }
            for(numberOfHashes = 1; numberOfHashes <= row; numberOfHashes++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + "#");
            }
            System.out.println(); // Go to next line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Darn, beat me to it! Was just about to print almost an identical answer! :)

Comment: Thank you, some one who actually solves instead of moans! Best answer. One little observation, there is a typo on the first loop saying numberOfHashes but you have solved my question! Thanks.

Comment: @paul - fixed the typo

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. I have selected your answer now.

Comment: `numberOfBlanks` is undefined. I'd suggest moving the declarations into the `for` loops, e.g. `for (int row = 1; ...`.

Answer (score 2):

You should write a descending loop of that print spaces. 
First line print 5 spaces. 
Second line print 4 spaces. 
And so on

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you show me please?

Answer (score 1):

```
int dimension = 6;
for(int i=1; i<=dimension; i++) {
    for(int j=dimension-i; j>0; j--) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    for(int x=i; x>0; x--) {
        System.out.print("# ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```